# How should i structure my app?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, tabactivity, drawerlayout

[image]

My android app currently uses TabActivity that has four tabs. I also use a third party navigation drawer that provides an easier way to navigate to these four tabs. I know, why have a navigation drawer when we have tabs right? This is what my organization wanted.The app also currently does not support tablets.

It is now time to redo our app from ground up. We need to add support for tablets too this time. I have been looking at the new Navigation Drawer provided by google and fragments. Because TabActivity has been deprecated, we don't want to use this anymore and google suggests us to use fragment instead. Tool that google provide such as navigation drawer and fragments are really powerful tool, but i am having a hard time structuring my app.

The app has four main tabs, All these tabs needs to have a navigation drawer. However, this needs to be a common navigation drawer, the items displayed in this navigation not only contains a link to navigate to these four displays but it also adds other functionalities.

As you can see from the attached image, 3 out of four tabs starts directly with the ListActivity. They need to be 3 different activity because all of them holds different informations and a user must be able to go from one activity to another.

When a user clicks on an item on the list, it will take them to the detailed view (Detail Activity). This detail activity also needs to have the same navigation drawer that the parent activity (ListActivity) has. On top of it, this view will add 4 more actions new actions to the navigation drawer. This view also needs to have a drawer that opens from right to left.

If a user is in the detailed view (Detail Activity)  by navigation through all four tabs, the user should be able to see different data depending on what item they clicked on the listActivity.

I was thinking i would do this using an abstract base activity class that holds the navigation drawer and all activity will use them. I was also going to use the master/detail flow pattern so that the it works with both phone and tablet. However, this plan got shot down after i found out that i cannot extend the base activity to use the navigation drawer.

At this point, i am lost as to what to do. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking in the wrong way. The way you are structuring your app is pre-Fragments based (an activity for every screen). Instead you should only make a new activity if there is a new interaction flow (I didn't notice any in what you described). So basically I would use a fragment for each screen and make them as abstract as possible so that you can reuse them. In this case you would only have one activity and you are simply switching in and out fragments. This makes implementing a uniform navigation drawer much easier (and really is the only way you should do it).

Hope that helps, happy to clarify anything with you. I remember when I first switched to fragments, it was confusing, but it's so much easier, especially when you start developing for phones and tablets.

Comment: So, I should have 1 activity that holds both navigation drawer left and right and i should constantly replace one fragment depending on if i want list fragment or detail fragment. When detail fragment is visible i should show the right navigation drawer otherwise i should i it. Is this what you are suggesting? If so, then how would you recommend managing the app for tablet? I can see how fragments will be useful, but it is so hard to visualize everything right now.

Comment: That is correct, though I recommend using some type of library to use navigation drawers as it will allow for more simple toggling of which ones to have active. As for tablet compatibility, try not to think of how to adapt the app for the tablet, instead redesign your user interface as if there was no phone interface. Then figure out what parts you can reuse from the phone layout and use them as fragments.